# Edit the create new section page

Tags: sections

When creating sections, I need a way to toggle all of them off or on. I have 188 sites and you can imagine how big of a pain it is to untoggle one by one.

Am I able to do this somehow? Create a module?

Edit: I've been told creating this many sites isn't a good idea, so perhaps this is a foolish question

[image]

Comment: Quantity of sites aside, I can see this as being a useful feature! The best thing to do is submit a feature request to the team. You can do that by [creating an issue](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues), and the Dev team will pick up on it.

Comment: @JamieWade, I'll do that!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript 'hack' in browser console:

```
$lightswitches.each(function(){
    var lightswitch = $(this).data('lightswitch');
    lightswitch.turnOff();
});
```